# Journey Builder Transactional API with SFDE not Creating IER

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi, transactional-messaging-api

Title says it all.

I have a Transactional API Journey Builder with a DE located in Salesforce Data Extension. I moved it from DE to SFDE as you cannot assign a SFDE directly from Journey Builder.
I read somewhere that you this setup does send tracking back to CRM as IER. But I could never got it to work. Do you guys have any advice on how to properly set this up.

Below is my payload in API call to: https://[domain].rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/email/messages

```
{
  "definitionKey": "transactional-api-event-2",
  "recipients": [
    {
      "contactKey": "0036g00000nbXdLAAU",
      "to": "test@email.com",
      "attributes": {
        "attr1": "someid",
        "attr2": "firstname"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending to Salesforce Data Extensions doesn't add that functionality to sends via transactional send journeys - this only works for single sends from email studio, etc.
As with the older triggered emails configured in email studio, the transactional messaging API doesn't create IERs at the moment.

However, I've got the confirmation from the product manager of the Transactional Messaging API, that this is one of the top 3 things on the short-term roadmap. I don't have a confirmed date unfortunately, but expect to see it later this year.

To possibly have it delivered more quickly, you could upvote the following idea on IdeaExchange: [Allow to send Tracking Data of Transactional Send Journeys to Sales Cloud](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000le97QAA)

**Related resources:**

- [Blog article "Transactional Send Journeys and the Event Notification Service"](https://markus.codes/2020/11/26/salesforce-marketing-cloud-transactional-send-journeys-event-notification-service)
- [IdeaExchange: Allow to send Tracking Data of Transactional Send Journeys to Sales Cloud](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000le97QAA)

Comment: Appreciate the quick response. I just upvoted the IdeaExchange. I wonder what this short-term road map entails. I hope that this isnt one of those functionality that actually takes years to implement. thank you so much.

Comment: From my call with the product manager it sounded link they are already working on it and it should be delivered within the next few releases. However, he couldn't confirm that officially.